# Thanks to Kevin and Thaddeus for their years of service as moderators

Tags: discussion, moderators

As some of you have already noticed, this month our site's moderator team lost two of its members. They hadn't been active for a while, and the Stack Exchange Community Team removed their diamonds under the [process for inactive moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338006/278659). Instead of focusing on their inactivity and removal, this meta post is to thank them for their years of service as moderators.

[image: Kevin] [image: Thaddeus]

**Kevin** joined the mod team in the [2013 election](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/election/2), the second election on SFF, in which he received [45 votes](https://www.opavote.com/results/947007/0) as first-choice candidate, among 200 votes cast for 7 candidates. Although [rarely posting Q&A](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3267/kevin?tab=activity&sort=posts) since his election, except on meta where he was [the first to get a tag badge in `support`](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/78/support) (excluding any now-deleted users), he remained active in mod duties for almost all of his diamond tenure, a total of more than **eight years** from 2013 to 2021.

**Thaddeus Howze** joined the mod team in the [2015 election](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/election/3), the third election on SFF, in which he received [over 100 votes](https://www.opavote.com/results/6319710861787136/0) as first-choice candidate, among 505 votes cast for 8 candidates. With over 100,000 rep on election and more than double that at the time of this post, he remains the third highest-rep user SFF has ever had, with over 1500 answers to his name. Although he was an infrequent visitor in recent years, he spent over **six years** as a mod from 2015 to 2021.

We don't have access to the mod task statistics for *former* moderators, but I remember that Kevin and Thaddeus handled **more than 1000 flags each** during their mod years. They were also the two  longest-tenured *users* among the mod team (although Thaddeus was elected after AncientSwordRage, he joined the site earlier, as is evident from user IDs).

Let's thank them both for their diamond years!

Comment: This meta is *not* featured, according to [rules imposed by SE last year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343528/278659) on featuring posts that name users :-(

Comment: If we got permission from them however, we could feature it.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - Thaddeus seems to be contactable by twitter

Comment: @Valorum Mhmmm, I already follow  them. But I have no such way to contact Kevin.

Answer (score 21):

## Thank you both

It's not easy moderating this site, but I'm glad that you've both done so to the best of your abilities.

It's a shame to see that your interest in this community seems to have dwindled, but I think we can all appreciate your candour in recognising that and stepping down.

All the best for your future endeavours!