# Brace yourself, an election is coming!

Tags: discussion, election

Normally, we the mods, would wait for the election day for the announcement that the election is live.

However given the [circumstances](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13342/3804), and the previous meta posts about moderators 'going missing' it seemed prudent to give everyone the heads up, so...

### [Brace yourself, an election is coming!](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/election/5)

Important details:

- nomination begins on Jun 7 at 20:00
- election begins on Jun 14 at 20:00
- election ends on Jun 22 at 20:00

There will also be time to ask nominees questions as well, but currently the 2021 election page is referencing the last election (2016) so watch this space.

Comment: Consider myself fully braced.

Comment: I forgot to brace myself and fell off my chair.

Comment: The User remembers!

Comment: @Valorum - your chair is like Death Star? No railings?

Comment: I'm watching this space, but nothing's happening.

Comment: How many mods are being elected this time around?

Comment: @valorum, patience young padawan....

Comment: @ibid, at the moment just one.

Comment: @ibid You can see that on the election page (top right).

Comment: @Valorum In space, no-one can see you watch.

Comment: Does this call for a "Watch [this space] Party"?

Comment: *Pours a double scotch*

I shall be properly braced within the hour...

Comment: In fairness, both leaving moderators went missing a year or more before they 'went missing'.

Comment: Freshly leaked, the secret mod oath : "Flags gather, and now my watch begins. It shall not end until my death. I shall take no prisoners, hold no hands, favour no users. I shall wear diamonds but win no glory. I shall live and die reading posts. I am the pitchfork in the manure. I am the watcher of the firewall. I am the shield that guards the site from spam. I pledge my life and honor to the Mod Team, for this year and all the years to come."